# Css - How to have my button make a clicking effect when I click It

Tags: css, button, styling

Hello I am having trouble with **css**. When I am styling a **button**
here is the code

```
.green-button{
border: none;
background-color: rgba(78, 200, 129, 0.911);
border-radius: 3px; 
color: white;}


.green-button:hover{
background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
border-radius: 3px; 
color: rgba(83, 211, 104, 0.911);
opacity: 7;
transition: all 0.4s;}
```

The problem is when I am clicking the button It just stays the same.
the button does not go a darker green or a lighter green.

I have been looking around on other websites and I have not
found any details when I go on regular sites I mostly check on to get my information.
If you know anything I can try please let me know.

Comment: Use `:active` for click effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `:active` pseudoclass, represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button.
From [Mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active?retiredLocale=it)

```css
.green-button{
border: none;
background-color: rgba(78, 200, 129, 0.911);
border-radius: 3px; 
color: white;}


.green-button:hover{
background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
border-radius: 3px; 
color: rgba(83, 211, 104, 0.911);
opacity: 7;
transition: all 0.4s;}

.green-button:active{
background-color:red;
color:white}
```

```html
<button class="green-button">Test</button>
```